# How do I count number of different types of things in a SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table storing a set of transactions

```
Customer | Flavor | Date Purchased | Location | blah | blah
Anna     | Apple  | 2014-01-01     | Seattle  | 1    | 0
Anna     | Grape  | 2014-01-01     | Seattle  | 1    | 0
...
```

I'd like to be able to select the number of different flavors each customer tried.

Like...

```
Who   | Number of flavors tried
Anna  | 4
Beth  | 1
Cathy | 100
```

And it's bending my brain into a knot. How do I group/join/? my way to victory?

Comment: When you want to put together the rows with the same value, you use `GROUP BY` on the appropriate column (customer). To get the number of rows put together in the group for each customer, you would add `COUNT(*)`, but in your case, you want to know how many of different flavors, so you have to `count(distinct flavors)` to get how many different ones for each customer.

Answer (score 4):

If you group by the `customer` then aggregate functions like `count()` are applied to every single group and not to the complete resultset.

`distinct` also only counts the **different** flavors.

```
select customer, 
       count(distinct flavor) as `number of flavors tried`
from your_table
group by customer
```

Comment: Seems to be some homework, you could probably add some explanations... don't just give him a fish...

Comment: While the example's generalized, I promise this is work-work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Customer,COUNT(distinct Flavor) FROM table GROUP BY Customer;
```